# Verify Security Certificate from AusCert

Tags: certificate, ssl-certificate

I have my security digital certificate for https signed by AusCert.
Given AusCert certificate and my security certificate, is there a tool to test whether it's a valid certificate or not (other than using web browser) ?

Answer (score 1):

There are [web based solutions](http://www.digicert.com/help/), but your best bet is to use a web browser.